# Python splitting of text

Tags: python

I have a text file (.txt) with different lines of words
For example:

```
1,2,3,4,5
11,12,13,14,15
```

How can I use the `file.read().split()` command to just get the 2nd column...so 2 and 12 for example of the text?

Comment: If you're parsing a CSV have you considered actually using [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no spaces around `,`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(',')[1])
```

If there could be whitespaces, use `re.split()`:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.split(r'\s?,\s?', line)[1])
```

Comment: I would use `strip()` before resorting to `re` in this case.

Comment: I am new to python...what is the re.split line do?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to split the file into lines (easily done simply by iterating over it), than you have to extract the 2nd column from each line.

Simple example:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        print(line.split(",")[1]) # indexing starts at 0
```

To accumulate a list of the values:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
    mylist = [line.split(",")[1] for line in myfile]
```

Comment: Maybe also pass a maxsplit arg to avoid doing extra work.

Comment: Yes, `line.split(",", 2)[1]` would probably be an improvement: good eye!